# How to extract only certain properties of json, returning as an observable using rxjs

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

For example this is the json which I am receiving,

```
{
    "events": [...
    ],
    "total": 12341,
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Apple"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Bob",
            "last_name": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Carrot"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to transform the data to the following form, and return it as an observable

```
[
    {
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Apple"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Bob",
        "last_name": "Banana"
    },
    {
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Carrot"
    }
]
```

I have tried the following, but it returns undefined.

```
getStudentsName(): Observable<any> {
    const requestUrl = this.rootURL + `students/`;
    let studentsInfo = this.http.get<any>(requestUrl).pipe(map(o => o.students));
    return studentsInfo.pipe(map(students => {students.first_name, students.last_name}));
  }
```

returns undefined when subscribing to observable

```
this.getStudentsInfoService.getStudentsName()
      .subscribe((result) => console.log('here', result));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, that students is an array, but you handle it as an object. You need to add a nested map: 1 for rxjs, **1 for the array**

```
return studentsInfo.pipe(
  map(studentsArray => studentsArray.map(student => ({
    first_name: student.first_name,
    last_name: student.last_name
  }))),
);
```

PS.: Using types instead of any would have shown you that. Neither you nor the other responders saw this issue due to missing typing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it can't find `students`. Try this :

```js
return studentsInfo.pipe(map(s => { return {
  first_name: s.first_name,
  last_name: s.last_name,
}}));
```

Comment: oh yea i just realized it, but it also returns undefined

Comment: You need to either specify a return or wrap the `{}` inside parentheses `({})`. Otherwise it will be treated as a code block instead of an object.

Comment: I am receiving this error after the changes, The parser expected to find a '}' to match the '{' token here.

Comment: Woops, looks like it was missing a set of curly braces

Comment: oh it returns a value now, but now, first_name: undefined, last_name: undefined

Comment: Try logging `s` to see what if it does contain `first_name` and `last_name` fields : `pipe(map(s => { console.log(s); return {`

Comment: `return studentsInfo.pipe(map(s => {return {
      first_name: s.map(b => b.first_name),
      last_name: s.map(b => b.last_name)
    }}));` I had to do this, but it is not returning the data in the format I want it to be

Comment: @pepega I highly recommend to add some types instead of any. The types could help you finding errors

Comment: That's strange, I can't reproduce it on the console. Can you add a jsfiddle or stackblitz example ?

Comment: studentsInfo is an array at his example and he trys to read properties from that array. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code snippet.

```
const object = {
    "total": 12341,
    "students": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "John",
            "last_name": "Apple"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Bob",
            "last_name": "Banana"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Carrot"
        }
    ]
}

let arr: any = [];
object.students.forEach(person => arr.push(
    {
        "first_name": person.first_name,
        "last_name": person.last_name
    }))

console.log(arr)


    [LOG]: [{ "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Apple" }, 
{ "first_name": "Bob", "last_name": "Banana" }, { "first_name": "Charles", "last_name": "Carrot" }]
```

You can iterate over students with a foreach loop and then create a new json which you then push in your new array

```
this.http.get<any>(requestUrl).pipe(map(o => o.students.foreach(person => arr.push({
...}));
```

Comment: The `forEach-push` aproach is a bad practice and should really be replaced by `map`

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The Problem is with your how you return your observable

Lets break the code down

```
let studentsInfo = this.http.get<any>(requestUrl).pipe(map(o => o.students));
```

In the above `studentsInfo` will be of type `Observable<any>`

Next line is as per below

```
return studentsInfo.pipe(
  map(students => {
    students.first_name, students.last_name
  }
));
```

Lets have a look at the below section

```
{
  students.first_name, students.last_name
}
```

This part of the section actually has **no return statement hence by default javascript returns undefined!**

### Solution

To use arrow function without a return statement, you will need to wrap `{}` inside a `()` like below

```
students => ({ })
```

Below will work

```
getStudentsName(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>(`${this.routeURL}/students`).pipe(
    map(o => o.students));
  }
```